# Identifying name of a connector part

Tags: repair, table, connectors

An old kitchen table has kind of spanning metal clips connecting parts; some of them are rusty and do not span well anymore.

Note: you might think that because of the rust the clips can't be closed anymore, but in fact they have somehow become weak, i.e. normally you would close and open them with applying slight force, but now the clips can just open up by themselves because of the gravity.

What is the proper name of this metal parts so that I could order and replace them?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The damage is superficial, you could unscrew them, drop them in a rust- removal solution, spray paint them, lubricate and replace them.

Comment: thank you! still is there a proper term for such parts? also, I think I need to add this, the closure has become weak, not blocked by rust.

Comment: If they are loose now it seems like there are two ways to fix it. First would be to slightly re-form the metal loop so it is tighter. It probably became stretched over time. The second way would be to re-position them to be farther apart from their mate. You'd need to move them so the old screw holes aren't in the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they are called latch clamps:

https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=latch+clamp&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Alatch+clamp